# custom adapter for spinner android kotlin not visible but visible when you click the dropdown values

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner, android-adapter

I have a spinner containing items from a web service, the value is only visible on the dropdown only. when I open the app the spinner is empty but if I click the spinner I will see the values in the dropdown. check the images for more info. Thanks
[image]

[image]

**XML**

```html
 <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_missions"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_padding"
            android:visibility="visible"/>
```

Please I need help to get the spinner value displayed.

Comment: This is Solution : **https://stackoverflow.com/a/69736715/11138845**

Answer (score 0):

Try adding spinner entries to the spinner widget

```
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinner_missions"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:entries="@array/entries" />
```

Then create your spinner entries values

```
<resources>
<string-array name="entries">
    <item>Stack</item>
    <item>Android</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="values">
    <item>100</item>
    <item>3000</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: I get the values dynamically from the server